# How do you generate 'replace' gifs with ffmpeg instead of 'cumulative(combined)'?

Tags: ffmpeg, gif

I'm using the following code to generate a gif using ffmpeg:

```
src="input.flv"
dest="output.gif"
palette="/tmp/palette.png"

ffmpeg -i $src -vf palettegen -y $palette
ffmpeg -i $src -i $palette -lavfi paletteuse -y $dest
```

The gif that is produced is '[cumulative](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/55311/how-can-i-modify-a-gif-that-uses-cumulative-layers)'. How can I change it so that the gif produced is 'replace' (where each image is independent of the previous)?

I realize this would result in a gif with a larger file size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to disable picture offsetting.

```
ffmpeg -i $src -i $palette -lavfi paletteuse -gifflags 0 -y $dest
```

Comment: Thanks! How did you find out about `gifflags`? It's not mentioned in the [docs](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html)...

Comment: Still gives the same cumulative result for me, even when using `-gifflags 0`. Is there another way? ffmpeg 4.1 on Windows 10.

Comment: dude, this was a life saver, thank you so much